# Can I have a console app run inside of a form app in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2013

I've made a little "labyrinth console mini-game" in C++ and I'd like to integrate it in a form application in Visual Studio so that I can save time trying to implement a good-looking menu in console.

The Console Game:

[image: The Console Game]

The Form Application:

[image: The Form Application]
Is this even possible?

(I'm still a beginner as you may have noticed)

Comment: Why is this tagged batch-file?

Comment: For sure it is possible, but I have hard time to suggest some simple way. So I will just show why it is possible: if everything else fails, you may run the console app internally and remap the std::in/std::out of it's instance to your form app I/O streams, and then display the output stream with graphic font rendering, and fill up input stream by input from UI. Then again, maybe there's even some ready-to-use widget to incorporate console into window? (common thing in IDEs, to show output of compilation, although those rarely work with input).

Comment: uh.. and that std::out way of course works only if you are using std::out for output. If you use some low level output like directly writing to text mode, or some ncurses-like library, it may be impossible to remap the output of the game to internal output stream.

Comment: Anyway.. in the end I would probably refactor the original C++ source to have I/O layer of code as separated from rest of game code, as possible, with some general interface, then I would include that source into the GUI app, and provide graphical implementation of those I/O interfaces, and connect that with the rest of original game code. This way you can learn also a thing or two why API-like interfaces are written the way they are, and how to provide different implementation thanks to them quite "easily", when reusing the code in other project.

Comment: It has been edited now, but FYI: the spelling is "lab**y**r**i**nth" (screenshot still has the wrong spelling).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response.  I'll be taking a look here and there to see what I can do.

(my bad for the typo)

Comment: You're not going to be able to remap out like that. You COULD read/write the entire console buffer using the windows API, but it's probably easier just to do the entire thing in your forms program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is probably to simply recreate the console functionality using a graphics library and a fixed-width or bitmap font (a la dwarf fortress). To my knowledge, you can't actually host a window inside another window like that even at the best of times, and console windows are a bit different from your standard window anyway.

GDI+ is probably the simplest, though slowest way to go. It's built into windows forms and is a very mature product with a lot of features, but it's not really designed with games in mind.

Direct2D might actually be a better option, which might be your best option since it's faster. It's a bit more complicated, but it's got a lot of optimization and is essentially a subset of Direct3D. It shouldn't be to hard to mash GDI+ and Direct2D together, either, though it'll take a bit of work.